# are normal subgroups of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ also normal under the action of integer matrices in $GL(2, \mathbb{Q})$?

Tags: matrices

Ie, if $\Gamma\subseteq\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is a normal subgroup, and $\alpha\in\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})\cap M_2(\mathbb{Z})$, then is $\alpha\Gamma = \Gamma\alpha$?

(if necessary we can assume $\alpha$ has positive determinant).

- will

Comment: Ah, you just changed your question, so I have to update my answer.

Comment: yeah, the title question was correct, but I made a mistake in the actual post.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your title carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is NO.

For example, let $\Gamma=SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ and let $\alpha=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\in GL(2,\mathbb{Q})\cap M_2(\mathbb{Z})$. 
Then for any $\beta\in\alpha\Gamma$, $\beta_{12}$ must be even, but this is not true for $\Gamma\alpha$.